# Global name 'method' is not defined (Difficulty passing parameter)

Tags: python, parameters, parameter-passing

I have defined and returned the value of variable 'method' to a function named method_menu, and then tried to parse it in to main. I've tried a number of things and I can't work out where I'm going wrong.

Here's the function where I define and return 'method':

```
def method_menu():
    #caeser or frequency
    print()
    print(".-METHOD MENU-----------------.")
    print("|                             |")
    print("|  (C) Caesar Cipher          |")
    print("|  (F) Frequency              |")
    print("|  (Q) Quit                   |")
    print("|                             |")
    print("`-----------------------------'")
    method = input("Press 'C' or 'F'").lower()
    return method
```

Here is main (trying to use the variable on lines 15 and 19) I initially thought I'd have to parse the parameter using def main(method, text) but it isn't recognized:

```
def main():
    # the main menu loop
    while True:

        # show the main menu and save their choice
        main_choice = main_menu(main_menu)

        # when they choose to quit break out of the infinite loop
        if main_choice == 'q':
                break

        # user chooses to cipher
        elif main_choice == 'c':
                method_menu(method,text)

        # user chooses to decipher
        elif main_choice == 'd':
                method_menu(method,text)

        else:
                print("Error - choice not recognised")
```

Here's the full program so far if it's of use to anybody: http://pastebin.com/e2M8K9Pa

Could somebody possibly tell me how to correctly parse paramaters to main?

Answer (score 1):

You assigned the return value of your `main_menu()` function call to the name `main_choice`, not `method`:

```
main_choice = main_menu(main_menu)
```

Simply pass *that* in to `method_menu()` instead:

```
elif main_choice == 'c':
    method_menu(main_choice, text)

elif main_choice == 'd':
    method_menu(main_choice, text)
```

You'll now get a name error for `text`; you never call the `get_source()` function anywhere nor assigned anything to `text`.

Next, `method_menu()` doesn't actually take any parameters; the function asks for more options before you can actually encrypt or decrypt. Call the function *without* parameters, then continue your program based on the return value. Presumably you want to call `source_menu()` as well.

Comment: Nope. The function in OP's upper code block is `method_menu` and doesn't take parameters.

Comment: @Carsten: right, but `text` is not defined either, that'll be the *first* error. `method_menu()` not taking any parameters is then the next.

Comment: Yeah, I was/am somehow under the impression that OP is trying to get the return_value of `method_menu` (called `method` inside the function) by passing something called `method` to the function as a parameter. But that's way too much guesswork without further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Function call and definition:** Function parameter for the `main_menu` is same name as function. Must avoid this.`def main_menu(main_menu):` and `main_choice = main_menu(main_menu)`
2. In our case it is not needed to pass any argument in function `main_menu`.
3. **Variable Name:** do not use same variable as function name, In code `main_menu` is variable name inside `main_menu` function. Must avoid this.
4. **Variable is not define**: `method` variable is not define in our code and we are using at line `method_menu(method,text)`.
5. **No argument for Function**: The `method_menu()` function not take any argument but in code we provide two `method_menu(method,text)` argument while calling this function, which is wrong.